# Is SendGrid configuration with GCP by default register the specific domain?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sendgrid

Is the configuration of Sendgrid with GCP domain specific?

Will sendgrid automatically allow the organization domain for sending Emails and reject all other domains, if the Signup for Sendgrid was done via Google Console.

Comment: Where are you configuring the SendGrid? On [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid) , [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/sendgrid)  or with [SendGrid Email API](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/marketplace/details/sendgrid-app/sendgrid-email)?

Comment: I will be using it Google Cloud Composer.